# Prove $\int_{a}^{c} f + \int_{c}^{b} f = \int_{a}^{b} f$

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

In terms of Calculus, it seems intuitive. Not sure how to formalize a proof.

**Pf**

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given.

Since $ \int_{a}^{b} f$ exists, $\bar{S}(f;P(\epsilon)) - \underline{S}(f;P(\epsilon))< \epsilon$

Since $\int_{a}^{c} f$ exists, $\bar{S}(f;P_1(\epsilon)) - \underline{S}(f;P_1(\epsilon))< \frac{\epsilon}{2}$

Since $\int_{c}^{b} f$ exists, $\bar{S}(f;P_2(\epsilon)) - \underline{S}(f;P_2(\epsilon))< \frac{\epsilon}{2}$

We have $P_1 \cup P_2 = P$

Then $\inf\{\bar{S}(f;P|P$ of $[a,b]\} \leq \inf\{\bar{S}(f;P_1|P_1$ of $[a,c]\} + \inf\{\bar{S}(f;P_2|P_2$ of $[a,b]\}$

Thus $\int_{a}^{c} f + \int_{c}^{b} f \geq \int_{a}^{b} f$

Similarly the supremum shows$\int_{a}^{c} f + \int_{c}^{b} f \leq \int_{a}^{b} f$

Thus $\int_{a}^{c} f + \int_{c}^{b} f = \int_{a}^{b} f$

Not sure how to show this holds regardless of the relative size of a,b, and c.

Comment: What about using the fundamental theorem of calculus?  Let $F(x)$ be an anti-derivative of $f(x)$.  Then $\int_a^c f(x)dx = F(c)-F(a)$.  Simplify the others similarly and reach the result.  Or, do you not have access to the fundamental theorem yet?

Comment: @JMoravitz Actually some textbooks do it the other way around, using this property to prove the fundamental theorem of calculus in the first place.

Comment: @JMoravitz It is not clear from the assumptions that the fundamental theorem of calculus can be used. One typically need some regularity on $f$ for that to be true.

Comment: A [proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Integrals_on_Adjacent_Intervals_for_Integrable_Functions) is given here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by sizes of $a, b, c$. I assume you mean the values that they take. In this case note that you can assume $a \le c \le b$ (all other cases are treated similarly) and you find: $$\int_{a}^{c}fdx = \int_a^bf1_{[a,c)}dx$$And: $$ \int_c^b fdx= \int_a^bf1_{[c,b)}dx$$
So the conclusion follows by additivity of the integral.